# woocommerce wc_rbp_product_selling_price in custom data tag

Tags: php, html, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In a site that I am developing in woocommerce I needed to be able to create 6 price lists with fixed prices for each product and to be able to apply a global discount in percentage for the price list assigned to the customer.

For the 6 price lists i've managed it through the plugin "Role Based Price For WooCommerce"

For the discount per client part i've created a little plugin. Here the code

```
function get_price_divider() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $perc = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'sconto_cliente', true );
    $sconto = ((int)$perc);
    return $sconto;
}


add_filter('wc_rbp_product_selling_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );

function custom_price( $price, $product ) {
  return ((int)$price)-((((int)$price)/100)*get_price_divider());
}
```

Everything works fine on the product page. It handle the hook 'wc_rbp_product_selling_price' correctly.

However, I need to pass this price to another plugin with which I made the "tool finder" for the products on sale.
The authors of the plugin (LSCF) give me the option to Create New Data Tag as specified here: https://pixolette.com/docs/lscf/custom-template/create-new-data-tag/

So i should display in their html template with this code

```
<div class="customdata">
Prezzo: {{post.custom_price}}
</div>
```

I've created the code below to do this but output always 0

```
add_action( 'lscf_custom_tags', 'lscf_custom_tags_function' );
function  lscf_custom_tags_function( &$args ) {
  global $price, $product;
  $post_id = (int) $args['ID'];
  $output = apply_filters( 'wc_rbp_product_selling_price', $price, $product );
  $args['custom_price'] = $output;
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but maybe you should reduce priority argument in the

`add_filter('wc_rbp_product_selling_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );`

It probably doesn't fire in time to adjust the price.